# Chrome devtools doesn't load after update. Any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After updating Chrome and applying windows 7 updates last night, Chrome devtools almost always won't load, getting stuck on loading the UI from appspot. After researching, rolling back a couple of restore points, trying different release channels, booting to safe mode, uninstalling reinstalling, switching to the 64 bit build, disabling extensions, deleting the devtools local storage, disabling commodo services, and more, the issue persists. I was encouraged after the windows rollback as devtools loaded a few times, but then stopped working again.

The rot actually started after first updating Chrome from either 48 or an earlier 49, with the debugger no longer showing file names for css entries other than bootstrap's, despite several css files loaded. Soon after, possibly from the windows update, devtools packed up completely.

Any more ideas to try aside from a complete windows reinstall or updating to W10 now?

Below is the image I get when hitting F12. Sometimes there is a black region.

[image: Devtools loading window]

**UPDATE:** A similar experience is happening at a different site without updating Chrome and also since, though the devtools interface does appear after about 20 seconds. So perhaps the delivery system for devtools is simply broken or impaired at the moment.

Comment: Maximizing devtools window fixes issue on my machine

Comment: Please make sure DevTools is in its own window (as it appears from the screenshot that it is.) Then press Ctrl + Shift +I when targeting that window. It should open DevTools on DevTools. This (assuming it gets a UX) should show  you any errors  in the console for what is happening. If the new window is blank as well, then debugging gets trickier and you should file a bug. https://new.crbug.com

Comment: @Garbee Thanks for that. I also fired up wireshark. The Devtools workspace maps to paths mounted via Samba on a VM over a VPN, and it seems to start scanning the files immediately. Other apps have no performance issues and Devtools was fine too, but I suspect this is what's causing the holdup now. Perhaps it's synchronously scanning rather than asynchronously. With your suggestion a second Devtools will not open while scanning, but after disconnecting the drive, Devtools opens fine and shows an error for the inaccessible path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is confirmed as being down to a drive mapping in the Devtools workspace and the number of files to be scanned, compounded by the files being over a VPN. Seemingly something changed with Chrome 49.0.2623.110 or earlier so that scanning of workspace paths now blocks the main Chrome process when Devtools is first opened whereas it did not previously.

The workaround therefore is to reduce the number of files to be scanned in Workspace locations, favouring more mappings with fewer overall files.